# How to execute a method after specific seconds for multiple time

Tags: java

I am using Timer for the scheduled run but not able to make it run for multiple times. I tried putting entire code under for loop but this doesn't seem to work it only prints `"Hello"` once. What am I doing wrong?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Timer t = new Timer();
    for(int i=1;i<=3;i++ ){
        t.schedule(new TimerTask()
                   {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {
                           System.out.println("Hello");

                           t.cancel();
                       }
                   },
                5000
        );
    }
}
```

**Update**: - The solution from @Ajay Kr Choudhary works but for termination of task, I would prefer `executorService.shutdown();` or `executorService.shutdownNow();`

Comment: ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate. will run your task repeatedly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use **ScheduledExecutorService** to achieve this. You need to invoke the `scheduleAtFixedRate` method of the executor service. Check the snippet below

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class SchedulerExample {
    //  counter to keep track of how many times thread has run
    static AtomicInteger runTimeCounter = new AtomicInteger(1);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        int totalCountToRun = 3;
        int threadSleepTime = 4;
        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (runTimeCounter.get() <= totalCountToRun) {
                    System.out.println("Hello");
                    System.out.println("Thread will sleep for " + threadSleepTime + " Seconds now");
                    incrementRunTimeCounter();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Have finished running for " + totalCountToRun + " times ..." +
                            "Will exit now from the application ...");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }, 0, threadSleepTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    static void incrementRunTimeCounter() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " incrementing it to: " +
                runTimeCounter.getAndIncrement());
    }

}
```

---

You may change the `initialDelay` and `period` parameter depending on the use case.

Have used the concept of `AtomicInteger` to increment the number of times the thread has executed. Keep a conditional check on this counter in run method to ensure it runs only for the number of times you want it to run. You can change the `totalCountToRun` variable depending on your use case.

Comment: How can I make it run for specific number of times? what is the parameter? Also, How does thread cleanup works in this case?

Comment: @skr You can use `AtomicInteger` for doing this. I have edited the code accordingly.

Comment: This is working but will not System.exit(0); kill all the threads running in the application?

Comment: @skr Yeah you are correct. System.exit(0) will exit the JVM itself. If you want to continue the execution after the run method as you said you can use the `executorService.shutdownNow();`. There is also a concept of shutdown hook in Java which you can use to gracefully shut down the running thread. Many people prefer that method for performing the cleanup.

Answer (score 2):

(edited)

As per my understading, timer.cancel() terminates the timer, but the loop gets completed. Cancelling prevents the run it to execute **again**, but the current loop continues.

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 

    // creating timertask, timer 
    final Timer timer = new Timer(); 
    TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() { 

        public void run() { 
            for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) { 
                System.out.println("working"); 
                if (i >= 1) { 
                    System.out.println("stop"); 
                    timer.cancel(); 
                } 
            } 
        }; 
    }; 
    timer.schedule(tt, 5000, 5000); 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't run the my code after 5 seconds from second iteration.

Comment: It doesn't. It executes the inner code at once not after every fiver seconds.

Comment: That's a different question. Schedule works for the timer's delay. If you want a delay between iterations of the loop, you can add a sleep. If you want, we can continue in a chat.

Answer (score 1):

Try using thread sleep method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            System.out.println("Hello");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }

    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```